GitHub - Criando Branch
Pessoal como verificar se a branch foi criada para o repositório correto?
Tenho vários arquivos de um repo clonado, devo criar uma branch para casa pasta?

"Uma branch para cada pasta" não faz o menor sentido. Um branch vale para todo o projeto - pense em branches como o "multiverso" do seu projeto, cada branch é uma "realidade paralela" que afeta todas as pastas e arquivos. Dito isso, o que vc quer dizer com "criada para o repositório correto"? Primeiro vc cria um branch no seu repositório local, e depois pode decidir se quer ou não enviá-lo para o remoto. Não deu pra entender o que vc quis dizer, nem o que precisa fazer...

Por favor, não duplique perguntas, se precisar comentar façam na postagem original: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/594093/3635
